# Preparing for Magento Developer Certification - Study Guide

Tags: magento, models

i'm preparing for the MCD exam and now i'm get stuck on chapter 4 work with database stuff. I allready could get the answers for some of the questions, but now i get to these ones where is no documentation.

Here are the questions i can not explain, even don't know exactly to what they refer to, and need some help to where i should look to be able to give some responses:

**

- 1.Describe the load-and-save process of an regular entity
- 2.Describe group save operations
- 3.Describe the collection interface (filtering/sorting/grouping)
- 4.Describe the hierarchy of database-related classes in Magento
- 5.Describe the role and hierarchy of setup objects in Magento

**

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT**

Munjals link to magento's Varien data collections is quite good for a basic understanding about how Models Collections works. However, the article does not give the right information to answer the questions I ask. Thanks again for Munjal.

Therefore, the question of me remains. I would be very grateful for more help and tips

My understanding of the questions:

**1.Describe the load-and-save process of an regular entity**

I think here are the load and save actions in the different classes which are used in this process. There are a lot an spread over the system. Also its important in which order the fire.

**2.Describe group save operations**

???

**3.Describe the collection interface (filtering/sorting/grouping)**

???

**4.Describe the hierarchy of database-related classes in Magento**

Do the question mean in which order the classes are instantiated and from where they inherit?

**5.Describe the role and hierarchy of setup objects in Magento**

??

Comment: Putting your PHP and MySQL knowledge into application and using this [http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) should be enough for the database chapter.

Comment: Hey Munjal, thanks, i will check the article

Answer (score 0):

1. its about orm not controller actions
2. its about transactions
3. its about what you can do with a collection since all collections extend the same abstract collection which gives you filtering, sorting, group by ....
4. check the class hierarchy of the orm related classes you use when creating your own eav and mysql4 models
5. installer scripts and setup classes should be watched in core and call hierarchy

Good luck ;)

Comment: Hey Mischa, could you be a bit more specific in which classes and areas i should look? to 1. was my mistake, i didn't mean controllers, but the methods in models like _beforeLoad() load() _afterLoad(). I think they want to know the classes instantiating and the order of function call. to 2. i dont understand it at least, what kind of transactions? 3. ok here are the methods of collection mean.